# Scan networks in AP mode (hostapd)

Tags: linux, wifi, hostapd

I want to scan networks when our devices is in Access Point. When the device is in client mode, it works, but i cannot scan networks if hostapd is running as Access Point:

Try 1:

```
pi $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Operation not supported
```

Try 2:

```
pi $ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the dmesg logs? (`sudo dmesg -c` first, then run your command, then post the logs when running `dmesg`)

Comment: also, what does `iwconfig` say?

Answer (score 2):

On Raspberry PI/wheezy, you may need to get the libnl library:

apt-get install libnl-dev

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. So I added ap-force to the command:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 scan ap-force
```

and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

Download iw v4.X from:
https://kernel.org/pub/software/network/iw/

Compile it and run:

```
./iw dev wlan0 scan ap-force
```

it works!